# Service to hit a url routinely

Tags: asynchronous, scheduled-tasks

As part of the beta testing of my new C# MVC project, I need to have a set of urls hit at routine times during the day.

I am aware of Pingdom, but is there any other suitable service available, or should I resort to finding some kind of browser plugin to do this for me?

Comment: You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484806/alternative-to-pingdom-website-monitoring-service

Comment: "Shopping list" questions are inappropriate here. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/172661 for one discussion of why that is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any kind of CronTab/CronJob.

For example: setcronjob.com